Constructing Joint Multivariate Normal Distribution from Marginal Distribution (detrended data)
I have two n-length data vectors $X_1 \sim N(\mu_{1},\Sigma_{1})$ and $X_{2} \sim N(\mu_{2}, \Sigma_{2})$ which may or may not have a covariance.  To see whether they do or not, I detrend them by rewriting them as $Z_{1}=\Sigma_{1}^{-1/2}(X_{1}-\mu_{1})$ and $Z_{2}=\Sigma_{2}^{-1/2}(X_{2}-\mu_{2})$ so that $Z_{1}\sim N(0,I_{n})$ and $Z_{2} \sim N(0,I_{n})$, where $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ is the square root of $\Sigma^{-1}$ ($\Sigma_{1}$ and $\Sigma_{2}$ are known) and then measure their true correlation by calculating $\operatorname{Cov}(Z_{1},Z_{2})/\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(Z_{1}) \operatorname{Var}(Z_{2})}$
My question is how can I find the ($2n\times 2n$) variance-covariance matrix for the joint multivariate normal distribution of $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ as parameterized by the correlation I calculated above.  I believe that fitting the correlation parameter by maximum likelihood should yield the correlation parameter I calculated between $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$.
For the general case of q-data vectors, how can I find the (qn x qn) variance-covariance matrix for the joint distribution of the original data in terms of the partial correlation coefficients calculated between all of the transformed vectors $Z_{1}$ through $Z_{q}$?
Thank you!
